# Having problems with when inserting module in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I inserted a module into the kernel with insmod command. But when Im testing it with an application Im getting this error.

```
 BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008
  IP: [<ffffffff812e67a9>] __sock_create+0x149/0x2c0
```

The application has a function sock_create which internally calls __sock_create. I kept printouts in that function but still was unable to figure out the problem . 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling `__sock_create` with invalid parameters.
This looks like you gave it a null pointer, and it accessed offset 8 of this address.